# Serializing object with no namespaces using DataContractSerializer

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, namespaces, datacontractserializer

How do I remove XML namespaces from an object's XML representation serialized using DataContractSerializer?

That object needs to be serialized to a very simple output XML.

- Latest & greatest - using .Net 4 beta 2
- The object will never need to be deserialized.
- XML should not have any xmlns:... namespace refs
- Any subtypes of Exception and ISubObject need to be supported.
- It will be very difficult to change the original object.

Object:

```
 [Serializable] 
 class MyObj
 {
     string str;
     Exception ex;
     ISubObject subobj;
 }
```

Need to serialize into:

```
<xml>
  <str>...</str>
  <ex i:nil="true" />
  <subobj i:type="Abc">
     <AbcProp1>...</AbcProp1>
     <AbcProp2>...</AbcProp2>
  </subobj>
</xml>
```

I used this code:

```
private static string ObjectToXmlString(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

    var serializer =
        new DataContractSerializer(
            obj.GetType(), null, Int32.MaxValue, false, false, null,
            new AllowAllContractResolver());

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
        Indent = true
    }))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(xw, obj);
        xw.Flush();

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

From [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/youssefm/archive/2009/06/05/introducing-a-new-datacontractserializer-feature-the-datacontractresolver.aspx) I adopted a DataContractResolver so that no subtypes have to be declared:

```
public class AllowAllContractResolver : DataContractResolver
{
    public override bool TryResolveType(Type dataContractType, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        if (!knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(dataContractType, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace))
        {
            var dictionary = new XmlDictionary();
            typeName = dictionary.Add(dataContractType.FullName);
            typeNamespace = dictionary.Add(dataContractType.Assembly.FullName);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null) ?? Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + typeNamespace);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to mark the classes you want to serialize with:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
```

In that case, the data contract serializer will not use any namespace for your serialized objects.

Marc

Comment: Some of the sub-objects are not under my control and I cannot change them. Is it possible to do it without changing the objects?

Comment: No, sorry - you cannot remove an existing namespace - you have to be able to specify the namespace on the object itself.

Comment: That can't be - what about all the system types? MS can't expect all types to be modifiable, there has to be some other way :(

Comment: No, there doesn't. It doesn't actually make sense for you to be removing namespaces.

Comment: So far I have implemented my own XmlWriter (delegating to the real one) that skips namespaces. Not clean, but it works. I suspect that DataContractResolver is capable of solving this for me... Will keep the issue open to see if any new solutions come forth.

Comment: This is actually printing `namespace = ""` in my xml :/

Comment: And dealing with namespaces is still a PITA several years later. Every program seems to interpret dealing with them differently, even .net apps vs. TSQL don't seem to play together well.

Answer (score 11):

If you have your heart set on bypassing the default behavior (as I currently do), you create a custom XmlWriter that bypasses writing the namespace.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class MyXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
  public MyXmlTextWriter(Stream stream)
    : base(stream, null)
  {
  }

  public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
  {
    base.WriteStartElement(null, localName, "");
  }
}
```

Then in your writer consumer, something like the following:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (var writer = new MyXmlTextWriter(ms))
  {
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    xmlDoc.Load(ms);
  }
}
```

And the output will have namespace declarations in it, but there will be no usages as such:

```
<TestObject xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Items xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <string>Item1</string>
    <string>Item2</string>
  </Items>
</TestObject>
```

Comment: XmlTextWriter giving me a problem to pass setting through constructor compare to XmlWriter

Comment: Were you not tempted to override `WriteStartAttribute` to get rid of the declarations as well?

Comment: @CarlosP Maybe, but I needed it namespace free for easy XSLT on the server, so that was my driving reason. If I were integrating this in WebApi serialization for xml I would definitely use your suggestion for lower load times.