# Serializing List<string> to xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datacontract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serializing object with no namespaces using DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851559/serializing-object-with-no-namespaces-using-datacontractserializer)

When I'm serializing object of this class:

```
[DataContract]
internal class Settings
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> AllowedEmails { get; set; }
}
```

I've got this XML as output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Commands.Settings">
    <AllowedEmails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <d2p1:string>asdsada</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>asdsada</d2p1:string>
    </AllowedEmails>
</Settings>
```

Is there a way to get rid of namespaces `xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Commands.Settings"` and `xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"`?

I know I can remove d2p1 namespace by doing this:

```
public Settings()
{
    [DataMember]
    public AllowedEmails AllowedEmails { get; set; }
}


[CollectionDataContract]
public class AllowedEmails : List<string>
{
    public AllowedEmails()
    {
    }
}
```

But may be there is more elegant solution?

Comment: Use `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer`.